# Evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^{\sqrt{x}}$. Euler's Limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits, exponential-function

Evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty}(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})^{\sqrt{x}}$.

---

Can I get some help? I am thinking that the limit does not exist. If you approach it from the left and then from the right, I think that the limits do not equal each other. I also suspect that we are dealing with Euler's limit, i.e.

*The limits $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty +} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ and $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty -} (1+\frac{1}{x})^x$ exist and both equal $e$*

Otherwise, I have little intuition to go from.

Comment: I edited that out, assuming it was a mistake. Apologies OP if that is incorrect.

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ does not exist when $x<0$ and $+\infty$ can be approached only from the left.

Comment: What does $\infty+$ and $\infty-$ mean? Do you mean $+\infty, -\infty$?

Comment: Note that in real analysis $\infty$ is not a real point. We merely use the notation $lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = L$ to mean $\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists M \in \mathbb{R}: \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\ x > M \implies | f(x) - L | < \epsilon$. This differs from the usual limit in that, instead of getting closer and closer to some value $L$ as we approach a point $a$, we now get closer and closer to some value $L$ as we make $x$ bigger and bigger. Consequently left- and right-limits do not exist for $\infty$.

Comment: In many books (imo, in **most** of them), writing the limit when $\;x\to\infty\;$ means $\;x\;$ approaches **plus infinity** , and there's only one way to approach this: from the left. For minus infinity we write $\;x\to -\infty\;$

Comment: The tag ([tag:eulers-constant]) is intended for questions about [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler-Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$, see the [tag-info](http://math.stackexchange.com/tags/eulers-constant/info). For questions about [Euler's number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%28mathematical_constant%29) $e$ you can use the tag ([tag:e]).

Answer (score 2):

When $\;x\to\infty\;$ we can assume $\;x>0\;$ when doing the limit, so now simply make a substitution:

$$x\leftrightarrow y^2\;\implies\;\;x\to\infty\iff y\to\infty$$

and your limit becomes

$$\lim_{y\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1y\right)^y=e$$

For negative $\;x$'s  $\;\sqrt x\;$ isn't defined and thus also the limit of your expression isn't when $\;x\to -\infty\;$

Answer (score 0):

Note that we can write

\begin{equation*}
\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{(\sqrt{x}\ln(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}))}
= e^{(\lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{x}\ln(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}))}
=e^{\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}})}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)}.
\end{equation*}

Applying L'Hopital's rule rule gives

\begin{equation*}
e^{\left(\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}}\right)}=e.
\end{equation*}